# How to remote log with Nginx

Tags: nginx, logging, rsyslog

Have anybody experience on remote access and error logging of Nginx?
We have such setup for Apache, but would like to migrate to Nginx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can have site specific access and error log in your project config or a global access and error log in your nginx.conf

Comment: With Apache we can define host messages coming to. Remotely. So local FS doesn't have any web server logs at all. According my search, I see I can setup remote logging with Nginx, but logging should come to local FS first which is we are trying to avoid.